# Lucky Bamboo : stems turning yellow, after I transferred the plants in soil

Tags: lucky-bamboo

I recently transferred (2 weeks back) my lucky bamboo plants to soil (after a lot of research on google/youtube), assuming it will grow good, but some of the stems turned yellow now and they are dying.

It was in water before this. Soil is 50% sand 50% vermicompost and plant is kept indoors.

Here are few pics -

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was growing in water prior to you planting it in soil, it needs to grow new roots.  The roots that plants grow in water are different then when they are planted in soil. A similar phenomenon happens, when a soil based plants is transplanted into a hydroponic system.  It sheds the old roots to grow roots that are more adapt to it's new environment.

Comment: I see.. I have removed the yellow stems now.. lets see how it grows...